# Why upcasting can be done directly in c#, but in order to downcast we require expilicit casting?

Tags: c#, oop

Consider two simple classes

```
public class Parent
{
    public void ShowData()
    {

    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public void GetData()
    {

    }
}

// Upcasting -- NO ERROR
Parent objParent = new Child();

// Downcasting  -- ERROR
Child objChild = new Parent();

// Downcasting -- NO ERROR
Child objNewChild = (Child)new Parent();
```

1. Why `UpCasting` does not require `explicit casting` ?
2. Why `DownCasting` requires `explicit casting` ?

Comment: Because how is it supposed to guess which child you want to cast to? (as you can have multiple children right)

Comment: @musefan: Because of the type of variable it's trying to assign to? That *could* be an implicit conversion, but it's not...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why UpCasting does not require explicit casting ?

Because it's always safe. It's never going to throw an exception.

> Why DownCasting requires explicit casting ?

Because it's *not* safe. It can throw an exception, or lose information (e.g. casting from `long` to `int` in an unchecked context).

The compiler's happy to let you do *safe* things implicitly, but if you're going to do something "dangerous", you need to effectively tick the box saying "I know what I'm doing here."

From the C# spec, section 6.1:

> The predefined implicit conversions always succeed and never cause exceptions to be thrown. Properly designed user-defined implicit conversions should exhibit these characteristics as well.

And section 6.2:

> The explicit conversions that are not implicit conversions<sup>1</sup> are conversions that cannot be proven to always succeed, conversions that are known to possibly lose information, and conversions across domains of types sufficiently different to merit explicit notation.

---

<sup>1</sup> All implicit conversions are also explicit conversions. That's just a technical point to make bits of the spec simpler.

Comment: Simple and clear. I think we all use casting and the compiler force us to do it right but indeed, your way of putting it is neat and can be easily understood. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Because a `Child` is a `Parent`, but a `Parent` is not necessarily a `Child`.  So a `Parent` can only be cast to a `Child` if the actual instance is a `Child` or a subclass of `Child`.  It's not guaranteed that some instance of `Parent` or subclass of `Parent` is a `Child`.  In the case you've presented `new Parent()` constructs an instance of the superclass.  It'll compile, but you'll get a runtime exception.

Comment: Excellent point, that the last example, which compiles, is guaranteed to throw at runtime.